# How to detect data races in Python applications?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, race-condition

It's not really clear what tools can be used to detect possible occurences of data races in python scripts, python code, or python-based executables.

I know that at least for CPython, only one thread is allowed to be executed to the GIL. But that doesn't mean data races cannot occur (for instance when two threads write an attribute on a structure, each with a value).

So how can I detect such scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've already done the obvious first step and looked through the code for non-atomic operations like `v += 1` on shared variables...

You can expand the window for race conditions to show up by increasing the frequency of a thread dropping the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). You can do so by lowering the switch-interval from its default of 5 ms. You can also insert `time.sleep(0)` around suspicious areas in the code to let a thread drop the GIL at this place if another one is trying to acquire it at that moment. Also randomizing the inserted sleep times ("fuzzing") is an option to further skew the execution order of threads.

Because it might not be clear to everyone what the point of doing this is:

Your code might work because a thread can comfortably walk through critical sections in it's 5 ms standard time slice and you get "lucky" with OS-scheduling during testing. Later you add some code and the critical sections suddenly is on the edge of the time slice and you get to note the race condition through weird bugs.

Demo code for letting race condition show up with help of changing [`sys.setswitchinterval`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.setswitchinterval):

```
from threading import Thread
import sys
# import time


def foo(n):
    global global_v
    for _ in range(n):
        x = global_v
        for _ in range(100):  # expand race condition for demo
            pass
        # time.sleep(0) # also: multiple locations with randomizing sleep times
        global_v = x + 1


def run(n_workers, n_iter):
    print(f"test with switch-interval: {sys.getswitchinterval()} sec")
    pool = [Thread(target=foo, args=(n_iter,)) for _ in range(n_workers)]

    for t in pool:
        t.start()
    for t in pool:
        t.join()

    print(f"expected: {n_workers * n_iter}, actual: {global_v}")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    N_WORKERS = 8
    n_iter = 1000
    global_v = 0

    # sys.setswitchinterval(0.001)
    run(N_WORKERS, n_iter)
```

Output:

```
test with switch-interval: 0.005 sec
expected: 8000, actual: 8000

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Output with `sys.setswitchinterval(0.001)`:

```
test with switch-interval: 0.001 sec
expected: 8000, actual: 7318

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This makes total sense for small to medium sized python applications and is a fast way to do so. I will try doing that and check the results.
But in more general cases and without *manually* touching the application's source code, do you know if there's a tool to dynamically instrument Python apps? Online resources are not very clear on that as well...

Comment: @MoKanj I haven't heard about such a tool, no. This would be non-trivial to create if possible at all with an interpreted language like Python.

Comment: Can you briefly describe would this be hard to do for Python code? (I dunno if I remember correctly, but there might be something similar for Java)
And wouldn't Valgrind be a candidate for Python?

Comment: @Darkonaut, is it really that hard for an interpreted language like Python to have support for detecting data races? Maybe I am over simplifying, but isn't all you need is to detect whether two threads are accessing same memory location one after the other (and at least one of them is a write) without any intervening synchronization mechanisms?

Comment: @DrPhil I'm afraid that's probably something only a core-dev could answer definitely. I just can't imagine how you would be able to collect the necessary meta-data in the first place or how you would check every possible execution-path to determine there's no data race. Regarding "simplifying", recall one of the three hard problems of CS is "just" cache invalidation.

Comment: @Darkonaut, sounds like we are both speculating about something we are not experts in. Though one observation I would make is that you don't have to find data races in all possible execution paths for it to be useful. For example "Go" has a built in data race detector, which only works for a "given" execution path at run time. Quote from [this page](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector)"The race detector only finds races that happen at runtime, so it can't find races in code paths that are not executed."